# When does convergence in distribution imply convergence of integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f$ in distribution, where $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of integrable functions. Also suppose $\sup_{n \geq 1} |f_n|$ is well-defined and measurable. Does this imply that

$$
\int_0^1 f_n \rightarrow \int_0^1 f
$$

I've tried thinking about convergence of the characteristic functions (Levy's continuity theorem) and also supposing that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in distribution. But I couldn't get to the result.

I don't think it is true given my attempts, since potentially you could use $f_n = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$, which are (i) integrable and (ii) have well-defined/measurable supremum on the interval (0,1). But $\int_0^1 f_n = 1$ and $f_n \rightarrow \chi_{(0)}$ in distribution.

Comment: Why do you consider $0$ so important? Just redefine $f_n(0)$ to be $0$ as I have done in my answer.

Comment: You get convergence in $L^1$ if $\limsup_n \int |f_n| \leq \int |f|$.

Comment: That makes sense to me @Mason, but I don't think this necessarily applies in this case, right? I think all that we can say is that $\sup_n \int |f_n| < \infty$, but not necessarily that $\limsup_n \int |f_n| \leq \int |f|$? So I think the counterexample applies (in particular $1/x$ is continuous on the interval $(0,1)$, so it is well-defined and measurable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the open interval $(0,1)$ with Lebegue measure define $f_n(x)=n1_{(0,\frac  1n)}(x)$ and $f=0$ Then $f_n(x)\leq \frac 1 x$ for all $n,x$ but $\int f_n$ does not tend to $\int f$. Note that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$.